# How to load ServerHttpSecurity in @SpringBootTest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I want to create a `@SpringBootTest` that makes use of my full configuration structure.

Problem: I'm creating an `@Bean SecurityWebFilterChain` that requires a `ServerHttpSecurity`, which is somehow missing in a test:

```
@SpringBootApplication  
public class MainApp { ... }

//for simple testing I started with anonymous auth
@Configuration
public class ReactiveSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.anonymous()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .build();
    }
}


@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void test() {
    
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'securityWebFilterChain' defined in class path resource [ReactiveSecurityConfiguration.class]:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'securityWebFilterChain' parameter 0;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity' available:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

**Update**

I discovered if I add the following annotations to my **Test** Class, the testmethod works without errors. But is that intentional?

```
@EnableWebFlux
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass { }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency pulled somewhere in the classpath. Removing it resolved the problem.

If both web and webflux dependency should be kept, it's still possible to run a test in reactive only, with:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.main.web-application-type=REACTIVE")
class MyWebFluxTests {

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain how your project is arranged, but no, it's not intentional. You can take a look at [Spring Security's Reactive Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/reactive/webflux/java/hello-security/src/test/java/example/HelloSecurityTests.java) that demonstrates this.

It may be that your `TestClass` is not finding the `@SpringBootConfiguration` annotation attached to `MainApp`.